# Impossible to make openVPN worked

Tags: openvpn, tunnelblick

Good morning,

I am trying to configure the minimal requirement for a VPN.
The server is a clean installation of centos 7 (I can try with others if it is simpler)
I have followed the instruction of this site https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-7-0-set-up-openvpn-server-in-5-minutes/
I also tried the manual way https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-centos-7

But when I try the connection with tunnelblick on mac I can only access site by their IP (so DNS problem), I added a PHP script on my server to have my public IP but it is still my old public IP that is used and not the new one.
It seems the VPN is not used at all

Also after a certain time tunnelblick show in console "

```
2019-04-05 19:14:50 Tunnelblick[59941] currentIPInfo(Name): IP address info could not be fetched within 34.3 seconds; the error was 'Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600001f05530 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://tunnelblick.net/ipinfo, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://tunnelblick.net/ipinfo, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://tunnelblick.net/ipinfo, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://tunnelblick.net/ipinfo, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}'; the response was '(null)'
2019-04-05 19:15:25 Tunnelblick[59941] currentIPInfo(Address): IP address info could not be fetched within 35.0 seconds; the error was 'Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600001fc76f0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://205.233.73.116/ipinfo, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://205.233.73.116/ipinfo, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://205.233.73.116/ipinfo, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://205.233.73.116/ipinfo, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}'; the response was '(null)'
2019-04-05 19:15:25 Tunnelblick[59941] An error occured fetching IP address information after connecting
```

I also tried with my android and with linux mint inside virtualbox with

```
openvpn --config cclient.ovpn 
Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in cclient.ovpn:21: tls-crypt (2.3.10)
Use --help for more information.
```

but line 21 is in middle of the encrypt key

and tls-crypt tag is present but after.

```
<tls-crypt>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
f3856bf6762970d83c25eccd966400dc
d6ec43b27660930701d6ebd6efbaa3da
...
```

this is the totality of the ovpn (don't care about security for the moment)

```
client
proto udp
remote 193.148.68.62 1194
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name server_BJMqmYrUxDaMZl3k name
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
cipher AES-128-GCM
tls-client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
verb 3
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
[private key redacted]
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<tls-crypt>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
f3856bf6762970d83c25eccd966400dc
d6ec43b27660930701d6ebd6efbaa3da
dee8e380cf94855e0f2ce1e9f832c4f6
613c6c51e97904b1e93182b2753bdcb8
c7f6573e74e8ce5640c329438b73241b
494a3935443f03717fd68dfe9c0d2bb5
755e9309b5e12a62452599bfaaef60ef
50f91463958edd07e4014c8503c8ed8f
da1ad0b1d42cdc169c3fbc1703b1662c
9ac3d32aa36254e73659d2f73ff44400
8e0a1692d808f7607111bf5becf32a91
5f2b44906b24a55939de881cb2406c25
80714f5aed426e1790950079f466afa2
7e61c35d2f6939479fab9e714813bb4c
00a71ce2954ff7bf8a0194622d0f21c6
4a00adf365708a59683468060ff23056
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-crypt>
```

so I don't really understand why it doesn't work. I have not installed firewall (firewalld is not installed) on my server an tun is activated.

if you have an idea to unblock the connection on linux mint or osx it will be helpfull.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolve the problem by following a totally different tutorial where the client software is included.
https://www.vultr.com/docs/installing-openvpn-on-centos-7

config :

- CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core) In open VZ with kernel
  2.6.32-48-pve
- openVPN version : openvpn-as-2.0.10-CentOS7.x86_64.rpm (library
  dependencies problems with newer versions)

I had to disable System Integrity Protection to make "OpenVpn Connect" works on mac and avoid "Error running jsondialog"

Step :

```
yum update
yum install net-tools
cd /tmp
wget http://swupdate.openvpn.org/as/openvpn-as-2.0.10-CentOS7.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh openvpn-as-2.0.10-CentOS7.x86_64.rpm

passwd openvpn
```

Choose a password

In chrome/firefox or others browser go to yourpublicip:943/admin connect with openvpn and the password chosen.
accept everything, then clic on the start server if he is stopped.

Go to yourpublicip:943 in browser and connect with the user openvpn again.

clic on download openvpn connect and enter login and password

for mac

if there is a json error http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/